# How to create multiple amazon SNS client in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I know how to read AWS credentials (for one environment) through application properties.
I need to create multiple amazonSnsClient() through application properties on application startup.

I have an application properties file that has AWS properties of multiple environments in one file which looks like below example

```
#DEV
abc.env[0].aws.accessKeyId=xaw
abc.env[0].aws.awsSecretKeyId=yrt

#TEST
abc.env[1].aws.accessKeyId=abc
abc.env[1].aws.awsSecretKeyId=def
```

I will have a HashMap that will contain all the AWS credentials from a properties file.

I need to read all the AWS Credentials from a properties file and create that many amazonSnsClient
How can I achieve the same in Spring boot? Is there any annotation that I can make use of?

**Note:** The requirement is that the properties of Dev and Test have to be in one file

Can someone please help?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the client manually like this ...

```
var client = SnsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of(awsProperties.getRegion()))
                .withCredentials(... add your credentials here)
                .build();

// use client methods to interact with AWS
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I need to create multiple clients, what is the best way to achieve in Spring Boot is there any annotation available? Do I need to use @Bean annotation?

Comment: You can use @ Bean with @ Qualifier annotation. Check this out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

Comment: If this answer has helped you please feel free to upvote and mark as accepted, so that others can find it and reuse it with confidence